# Redirect specific URLs by analyzing the querystring using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

On my current website I use parameters in querystrings to select the content shown to the user (e.g. www.domain.tld/index.php?site=linklist&page=2). I want to switch to wordpress and have all old links redirected to the new permalinks of wordpress.

When having `site=linklist` in the query string the user should be redirected to www.domain.tld/my-new-linklist . If the querystring contains `site=about` the user should be redirected to www.domain.tld/about-me ,...

How can I realize this using htaccess?

Comment: What have you tried so far, which part did you not get to work? This forum is about helping with specific problems. Not for having others do your homework. Read the excellent documentation, look at examples and have a try yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, try adding these above any of your wordpress rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|.*)site=linklist&?($|.*)
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /my-new-linklist?%1%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|.*)site=about&?($|.*)
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /about-me?%1%2 [L,R=301]
```

etc.

Any other query string gets passed along, but the `site=something` is stripped out.